# Copy 6 byte array to long long integer variable

Tags: c, long-integer, memcpy

I have read from memory a 6 byte `unsigned char` array.
The endianess is Big Endian here. 
Now I want to assign the value that is stored in the array to an integer variable. I assume this has to be `long long` since it must contain up to 6 bytes.

At the moment I am assigning it this way:

```
unsigned char aFoo[6];
long long nBar;
// read values to aFoo[]...
// aFoo[0]: 0x00
// aFoo[1]: 0x00
// aFoo[2]: 0x00
// aFoo[3]: 0x00
// aFoo[4]: 0x26
// aFoo[5]: 0x8e
nBar = (aFoo[0] << 64) + (aFoo[1] << 32) +(aFoo[2] << 24) + (aFoo[3] << 16) + (aFoo[4] << 8) + (aFoo[5]);
```

A memcpy approach would be neat, but when I do this

```
memcpy(&nBar, &aFoo, 6);
```

the 6 bytes are being copied to the `long long` from the start and thus have padding zeros at the end.
Is there a better way than my assignment with the shifting?

Comment: try with | (or) instead of + (plus) and don't forget to cast aFoo[0] to a 64 bit value because these kind of operations take place by default on 32 bit values in C

Comment: Is `(aFoo[0] << 64)` a typo? I think it should be `(aFoo[0] << 40)`

Comment: `(aFoo[0] << 64) == 0` on 64-bit integers. It should be `(aFoo[0] << 40)`.

Comment: memcpy and then bitshift the `long long` is what I would do.

Comment: Your shifts look wrong, e.g. shouldn't it be `aFoo[0] << 40`, not `aFoo[0] << 64` ?

Comment: If value in aFoo is big endian, what is your host endianness? Is nBar little endian?

Comment: 2 questions: Do you need a signed value? And do you want the value left (ie.e. to the MSbit) or right (i.e. to the LSbit) aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to accomplish is called de-serialisation or de-marshalling.

For values that wide, using a loop is a good idea, unless you really need the max. speed and your compiler does not vectorise loops:

```
uint8_t array[6];
...
uint64_t value = 0;

uint8_t *p = array;
for ( int i = (sizeof(array) - 1) * 8 ; i >= 0 ; i -= 8 )
    value |= (uint64_t)*p++ << i;
```

// left-align
   value <<= 64 - (sizeof(array) * 8);

Note using `stdint.h` types and `sizeof(uint8_t) cannot differ from`1`. Only these are guaranteed to have the expected bit-widths. Also use unsigned integers when shifting values. Right shifting certain values is implementation defined, while left shifting invokes undefined behaviour.

If**f** you need a signed value, just

```
int64_t final_value = (int64_t)value;
```

after the shifting. This is still implementation defined, but all modern implementations (and likely the older) just copy the value without modifications. A modern compiler likely will optimize this, so there is no penalty.

The declarations can be moved, of course. I just put them before where they are used for completeness.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a solid approach. On the last iteration however in the last iteration, `i` must not get decremented below `0`.

Comment: @tzippy: My fault; I started with an incrementing loop and use `size_t` for indexing an array (that is the most correct type actually), but then I optimised the loop. Note that you should be careful about the byte-ordering. As given, you have big-endian; for little-endia, you have to reverse the loop (it is most times benefical to process the array in ascending order).

Comment: One additional note on signed values: If original array value is to be interpreted as a signed type (for example, `{ 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF }` should be interpreted as `-1`), then additional code is need to handle 2 missing bytes to convert negative values correctly. Question was a little unclear if this is the case.

Comment: @user694733: `0xFF` is not a negative value. Hex constants are positive and have the type with the lowest rank that can represent it and is at least `int`. As the value is left-aligned, the sign is preserved for most (if not all) implementations. Only the 16 LSBs are zeroed (as required by the question). Note that having the bytes (sic!) themselves signed is of no use.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Signedness of individual bytes is not the point. If `aFoo` should be interpreted as a 48-bit signed integer, (which is, for example, read from binary file) then code expanding it to 64-bit signed integer needs to handle negative values. It seems to me that OP wanted the top 16 MSBs be handled, not the LSBs.

Comment: @user694733: Sorry, I'm no clairvoyant; just have to interpret what you write. Anyway, "padding zeros at the end." in the question is quite clear to me; even more as the first shift (64) also looks as if he intended that. Anyway, I asked for clarification.

Answer (score -2):

You might try

```
nBar = 0;
memcpy((unsigned char*)&nBar + 2, aFoo, 6);
```

No `&` needed before an array name caz' it's already an address.

Comment: Too bad this was down voted. As the OP's preference was to use memcpy this is exactly how this can be done I think.

Comment: This is a bad approach, as it makes some assumptions which are not guaranteed.

Comment: @Olaf could you please tell me what the assumptions are?

Comment: E.g. Alignment, encoding, endianess.