# How to read 64 bits from a pointer to an 8 bit value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, indexing, casting

I have created an array to represent virtual memory, and have a uint8_t* to this array. I am trying to access 64 bits at once, and set it equal to a value. It only takes in the first byte, and I can't figure out how to get it to take in the entire 64 bits.

```
control->value = memory[pc + 2];
```

I know this will set control's value to the memory array at pc+2 (the start of the 64 bits I'd like to read in)

I just don't know how to get this code to take in 64 bits into control-> value (a uint64_t)

Comment: Read 8 bytes and merge them using bitops. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597378/copy-6-byte-array-to-long-long-integer-variable/35600189#35600189) should help.

Comment: adding details about the data types of the variables could help to gain a clear idea.

Comment: @AbhishekChoubey: They are hidden in the text.

Comment: by changing the data type of "value" from uint8_t* to uint64_t*.

Comment: @AbhishekChoubey: ... which invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is to read a byte at a time and then shift and OR the value in.

If MSB is first:

```
control->value = (uint64_t)memory[pc + 2] << 56;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 3] << 48;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 4] << 40;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 5] << 32;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 6] << 24;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 7] << 16;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 8] << 8;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 9];
```

If LSB is first:

```
control->value = (uint64_t)memory[pc + 2];
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 3] << 8;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 4] << 16;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 5] << 24;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 6] << 32;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 7] << 40;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 8] << 48;
control->value |= (uint64_t)memory[pc + 9] << 56;
```

The casting is necessary to ensure that the left shifts don't "fall off the edge".

Comment: Please never do the first option. It's not portably, violates the strict aliasing rule and generally a bad idea.

Comment: I just didn't want to insult you by being too explicit ;-)

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to figure out, thank you very much!

Comment: @Anon Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

As in the below way you can access the 64 bit value with an `uint8_t*`

```
int main()
{
    uint64_t value = 100000000000;
    printf("%lld\n",value);
    uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)&value;     
    printf("%lld\n",*((uint64_t*)(ptr)));//While accessing the value you need typecast it back to uint64_t type.
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: How it is showing undefined behavior, Please Explain.

Comment: (If you answer to another comment, please use `@name`  to address the person. Just take the [tour] and follow site rules) Said that: Wrong format string. For another (and possibly more serious) UB, I was misslead by the code. The code only shows you can cast a pointer to one type to a `unsigned char *` and back. Not how to unmarshal an `uint64_t`. You do not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct some_struct{
    uint64_t value;
};
int main(void){
    uint64_t memory[10] = {111111111,22222222,0x1111111111111111,444444444,5,6,7,8,9,20};
    struct some_struct *control = malloc(sizeof(struct some_struct));
    int pc = 0;

    control->value = memory[pc+2];
    fprintf(stderr, "ptr = %llu, %llu\n", control->value, memory[2]);
}
```

Here I am trying to access the 3rd element of the "memory" which is an array
of 64 bit integers.
Hope this helps.